# Cannot install PHPExcel in Laravel 10 by psr-0 error

Tags: excel, laravel

I have tried to install Laravel Excel in Laravel 10, but I cannot install it.
I am using

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

but when I install it, it give an error like this.

```
> Class PHPExcel_Properties located in
> D:/project/real/laravel/testexcel/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes\PHPExcel\Chart\Properties.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping. Class
> PHPExcel_Best_Fit located in
> D:/project/real/laravel/testexcel/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\trend\bestFitClass.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping. Class
> PHPExcel_Exponential_Best_Fit located in
> D:/project/real/laravel/testexcel/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\trend\exponentialBestFitClass.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping. Class
> PHPExcel_Linear_Best_Fit located in
> D:/project/real/laravel/testexcel/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\trend\linearBestFitClass.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping. Class
> PHPExcel_Logarithmic_Best_Fit located in
> D:/project/real/laravel/testexcel/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\trend\logarithmicBestFitClass.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping. Class
> PHPExcel_Polynomial_Best_Fit located in
> D:/project/real/laravel/testexcel/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\trend\polynomialBestFitClass.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping. Class
> PHPExcel_Power_Best_Fit located in
> D:/project/real/laravel/testexcel/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\trend\powerBestFitClass.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

Please help. I still don’t understand why.
I am using `php 8.1`

here is my composer.json

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with `composer.json` file?
Errors are located in `phpoffice/phpexcel` but this package archived and it was used in old versions of `mattwebsite/excel` and from version 3 of `mattwebsite/excel`, `phpoffice/excel` dependency replaced with `phpoffice/spreadsheet`

Comment: @AmooAti i have update the question with composer json

Comment: `composer require maatwebsite/excel:"^3.1"`

Comment: As @IGP said, use the lastest version, you are using old 1.1 version

Comment: @AmooAti yes, but icant install the latest version

Comment: it automaticly intall the 1.1 version

Comment: @IGP still cannot install it, 
the error is 
>  Problem 1                                                                                                                                                                                   
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel 3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0].                                                                                           
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Manually change the package version in `composer.json` file and then use `composer update` to download new packages and generate a new lock file. you can also use strict versioning like `composer require maatwebsite/excel:"3.1.48"` and if it was ok change it to what IGP said

Comment: You tried to install version 3.1.0 (`:"3.1"`) instead of "any version 3.x that is bigger than 3.1" (`:"^3.1"`). Try reinstalling the package with `composer remove maatwebsite/excel && composer require maatwebsite/excel`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you upgrade maatwebsite/excel to newest version, according to https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel
Newest version is 3.x.x

Sorry I can not comment on your post.

As for your case, you could use 3.1.48 which supports both PHP7.x and PHP8.x.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel -W
```

This option will update dependencies and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As IGP Said, first you could try to uninstall maatwebsite/excel

```
composer remove maatwebsite/excel
```

Then try to install with all dependecies and adding the most recently version (3.1.48 for February 2024)

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel:"3.1.48" -W
```

If you have an error like this

```
  Problem 1
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.29.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.48 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.29.0].
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel 3.1.48 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.48].
```

Open your php.ini file and find the extension **gd**, enable (uncomment or/and install) and try again.

I'm using PHP 8.1.27 and it worked for me.

Comment: Well done! I don't know if the solution works, but thank you for both formatting and explaining your answer. Best of luck to you.